# sort the results from `apt-cache search <keywords>`

Tags: command-line, apt, apt-cache

Is there a way to sort the results from `apt-cache search <keywords>`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Pipe the result to `sort`:

```
apt-cache search keyword | sort
```

The vertical bar is called [pipe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29). It takes the output from `apt-cache` and transfers it to the input of `sort`.

Comment: `apt-cache search keyword | sort | less` . This way you can page up/down through results, can search using `/<filter-word>` or show only matching lines with `&/<filter-word>` . Press `n` for next result, `N` for previous.

Answer (score 3):

You can pipe the output of apt-cache search to [`popsort.py`](https://gitlab.com/d3k2mk7/rutils/blob/master/bin/popsort.py) (see footnotes) which sorts it in the increasing order of popularity and displays a popularity rank at the beginning.

For example, a typical apt-cache search run might look as

```
$ apt-cache search sqlite browser             
alice - Web browser (WebKit or Gecko) based IRC client
gtkcookie - editor for cookie files
hoteldruid - web-based property management system for hotels or B&Bs
nova-consoleauth - OpenStack Compute - Console Authenticator
ruby-http-cookie - Ruby library to handle HTTP Cookies based on RFC 6265
sqlitebrowser - GUI editor for SQLite databases
```

If the output is piped to `popsort.py`

```
$ apt-cache search sqlite browser | popsort.py 
66341 hoteldruid - web-based property management system for hotels or B&Bs
58787 nova-consoleauth - OpenStack Compute - Console Authenticator
43444 alice - Web browser (WebKit or Gecko) based IRC client
36506 gtkcookie - editor for cookie files
8052 ruby-http-cookie - Ruby library to handle HTTP Cookies based on RFC 6265
7114 sqlitebrowser - GUI editor for SQLite databases
```

which shows that `sqlitebrowser`, `ruby-http-cookie` are popular by an order of magnitude compared to others.

#### Footnotes

1. popsort.py is a python script I wrote. It requires Python3. The latest version can be found [here](https://gitlab.com/d3k2mk7/rutils/blob/master/bin/popsort.py) or just

   ```
   wget https://gitlab.com/d3k2mk7/rutils/raw/master/bin/popsort.py
   ```
2. [Latest documentation](http://raju.shoutwiki.com/wiki/Sort_output_of_apt-cache_search_by_popularity)
3. The script gets the popularity rankings from [popcon.debian.org/by_inst](https://popcon.debian.org/by_inst) which is good enough for Debian users. You may have to edit it accordingly for Ubuntu.
4. I had to break the URLs since the website does not allow new users to post URLs unless they have 10 reputation points (which I do not!).